# No puedo usar mis scripts de JS en Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: javascript, zend

Para agregar un script al sitio se usa el siguiente comando:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/script.js', 'text/javascript');
```

Y a la hora de probar el sitio aparece esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Pero no carga el script, en la consola del explorador aparece:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Y el contenido del archivo /js/script.js es la pagina principal.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Inicio -
```

No se porque no carga el archivo js, estoy usando Zend Framework 1.12.0

Comment: Si ese es el contenido del fichero es normal que no lo cargue: no contiene código Javascript, sino HTML

Comment: Si lo que intentas usar es _javascript_, tal como dice @PabloLozano, el código no corresponde a lo que se pretende usar. Si por el contrario, lo que estas es intentando cargar porciones de código _Html_ en el _layout_ lo que necesitas usar es el _ViewHelper_ [Partial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial).

Comment: El error que tenia era que esta probando el servidor con el comando `php -S  localhost:8080` y apuntaba directamente a `public/index.php` y como no era un servidor de apache la configuración del `.htaccess` no funcionaba. Entonces cuando intentaba cargar un archivo de la carpeta `public` que no fuera `index.php` de igualmenara cargaba el direcctorio raiz `/` entonces al cargar el archivo `/js/script.js` mostraba era la pagina principal. Me di cuenta de esto porque en el servidor de producción no había problemas al cargar los archivos.